# Bootstrap Flexbox Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I was trying to study bootstrap flexbox and I am trying to accomplish this layout

So what I did is that I added `d-flex flex-column` on each of the main div. However it did make all of them flexbox.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container wrap">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-22 mx-auto">
              <header class="bg-danger">
                  <navbar>
                     <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </navbar>
              </header>
              <div class="main d-flex flex-column">
              <aside class="bg-info text-white p-2">                
              <h3>Sidebar</h3>
              <p>Ikuo iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
              </aside>
              <div class="bg-light flex-grow-2 p-2">
              <h3>Content</h3>

          </div>
           </div>
          <footer class="p-2">
             <p class="bg-secondary flex-grow-2 text-white">Text</p>
             <p class="bg-primary flex-grow-1 text-white">Text</p>
          </footer>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering how can I use the `flex-grow-*` properties to attain exact the same layout as below?

Any idea how to attain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're missing `d-flex` classes for your footer and nav.

Here's the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/9dbj5w6x/

Comment: Also the side bar and main content did not sit next to each other like the picture above

Comment: Main content on the left and sidebar on the right.